# how do i sort my array of objects in ascending order of a string object?

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, sorting

I have to take user input of (int id, String title, String folder, int pages). I have to get the output in ascending order of string title(lexicographical). I have written the code, but i output is quite different.

```
package zzz;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

class Book{
    int id;
    String title;
    String folder;
    int pages;
}


public class practice {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Book b1 = new Book();
    Book b2 = new Book();
    Book b3 = new Book();
    Book b[]= {b1,b2,b3};
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        b[i].id=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
    b[i].title=sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
        b[i].folder=sc.next();
        b[i].pages=sc.nextInt();
    }
    Book temp = null;
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<b.length-1-i;j++) {
            if(b[i].title.compareTo(b[j].title)<0) {
             temp =b[j];
            b[j]=b[j+1];
            b[j+1]=temp;
        }}
    }
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(b[i].id+" "+b[i].title+" "+b[i].folder+" "+b[i].pages);
    }

    }}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implements Comparable to get alphabetical sort with Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871583/implements-comparable-to-get-alphabetical-sort-with-strings)

Comment: Does the Book class assign a default value to its title?

Comment: @Bohemian, no it doesn't

Comment: Then your problem is that title is null and you’re invoking the `compareTo()` method on a null object.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the class at the beginning and add the class after the main method as:

```
static class Book implements Comparable<Book>{
    int id;
    String title;
    String folder;
    int pages;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book other) {
        //If this is backword then switch it to -> other.title.compareTo(this.title);
        return this.title.compareTo(other.title);
     }
}
```

Same as: [Implements Comparable to get alphabetical sort with Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871583/implements-comparable-to-get-alphabetical-sort-with-strings/22871620)

Then you can just get the array of books and use `Arrays.sort(book_arr);`

For you:

```
package zzz;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class practice {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Book b1 = new Book();
    Book b2 = new Book();
    Book b3 = new Book();
    Book b[]= {b1,b2,b3};
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        b[i].id=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        b[i].title=sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
        b[i].folder=sc.next();
        b[i].pages=sc.nextInt();
    }

    //Sort!
    Arrays.sort(b);

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(b[i].id+" "+b[i].title+" "+b[i].folder+" "+b[i].pages);
    }

    }
    static class Book implements Comparable<Book>{
        int id;
        String title;
        String folder;
        int pages;

        @Override
         public int compareTo(Book other) {
             return this.title.compareTo(other.title);
         }
     }
}
```

[image: It works!]

Comment: didn't get you, can you please amend my code and help me out

Comment: thanks a lot. i amended my code in a diff manner, but the output is coming different. it should come aa, cc, ss but its coming aa ss cc. please have a look

Comment: Fixed! Here is the new code.
I have tested in eclipse and it has worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the NullPointerException because `b[i].title=sc.next();` is commented out.

A way of doing this without making Book Comparable is to sort a Stream:

```
Stream.of(b)
    .sorted((thisBook,anotherBook) -> thisBook.title.compareTo(anotherBook.title))
    .forEach(bk -> System.out.println(bk.id+" "+bk.title+" "+bk.folder+" "+bk.pages));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle your problem using `stream` in java 8, so instead of using `array`, you can use `List`, then you must **stream** it, **init** it, and finally **sort** books based on their `title`.

### **In summery**

1- Create Book objects (the same as yours)

2- Create Book list (Instead of an array)

3- **Stream** bookList, **Init** each book object then **Sort** them based on the title

4- Print the result

I coded your scenario as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        //Create Book Objects
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Book b1 = new Book();
        Book b2 = new Book();
        Book b3 = new Book();

        //Create BookList
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        bookList.add(b1);
        bookList.add(b2);
        bookList.add(b3);

        //Stream bookList, Init Books, Sort them based on the title
        bookList.stream().peek(book -> {

            //Init book objects (id , folder , title , pages)
            book.id = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            book.folder = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            book.title = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
            book.pages = sc.nextInt();          

        }).sorted(Comparator.comparing(book -> book.title)).collect(Collectors.toList());


        //Print results
        bookList.forEach(book -> {
            System.out.println(book.title);
        });
    }
```